# Math behind various optimizers in deep learning

Tags: reference-request, optimization, book-recommendation, machine-learning, online-resources

I am looking forward to learn the math behind the various optimizers present in neural networks such as adam,sgd,etc. Through this, I want to learn what makes one optimizer better than another for a particular case. Is anyone aware of resources that explain the math behind the various optimizer in deep learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These algorithms are based on linear algebra, multivariable calculus and probability theory (when the algorithms are stochastic). Specifically, rather than attempting to learn generic results from these branches, I would recommend starting with reviews of different optimisation algorithms, such as [[1](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/37341665.pdf)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/37341665.pdf) or the more in-depth [[2](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4419-0699-1%2F1.pdf)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-1-4419-0699-1%2F1.pdf), and refer back to Khan-academy/Wikipedia if some of the mathematical formalisms are unclear.

Once you have gained an overview and intuition of a few basic algorithms, you should start reading the relevant literature on optimisation in deep learning, c.f. [3](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~szhengac/papers/pqe.pdf), [4](https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icml11-OptimizationForDeepLearning.pdf) for reviews, and then the relevant references from these articles.